# Remainders of previously uninstalled icecc present when compiling go

Tags: go

On a linux machine I had icecc (distributed compiler) installed, which is now removed with `apt purge`.
When I start a simple go program I get the following compiler output:

```
└─$ go run .
# runtime/cgo
ICECC[32220] 2023-03-01 22:07:53: got exception Error 24 - remote 192.168.0.106 unable to handle environment (192.168.0.106)
# runtime/cgo
ICECC[33408] 2023-03-01 22:07:54: flush_writebuf() failed(Error: Broken pipe)
ICECC[33408] 2023-03-01 22:07:54: remote status: compiler did not start
ICECC[33408] 2023-03-01 22:07:54: write of source chunk to host 192.168.0.106
ICECC[33408] 2023-03-01 22:07:54: failed (Error: Broken pipe)
ICECC[33408] 2023-03-01 22:07:54: got exception Error 15 - write to host failed (192.168.0.106)
# runtime/cgo
[...]
```

The go program compiles starts as expected.
Interestingly, the date and time of the error output do not match the time when the `go run .` command was started.

How can I get rid of the annoying messages?

Answer (score 1):

I managed to get rid of the messages by deleting the
`~/.cache/go-build` folder